# Inferred latch warning on out port in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Disclaimer: this is beginner question.

I can't figure out why o_address gives an inferred latch warning in post-synthesis and how to fix it. 
When I try to assign it it gives another warning: design project has port o_address driven by constant 0. 
I have also tried to assign it in every single case but it still doesn't fix it.

Any tip is much appreciated.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity project is
    Port ( i_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           i_start : in STD_LOGIC;
           i_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
           o_address : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
end project;

architecture Behavioral of project is
    type state_type is( RST, S0 );  --other states
    signal CURRENT_STATE, NEXT_STATE : state_type;

    begin
    process(i_clk, i_rst, i_start)
    begin

    if(i_clk'event and i_clk = '1') then
        if(i_rst = '1') then
            CURRENT_STATE <= RST;
        else
            CURRENT_STATE <= NEXT_STATE;
        end if;
    end if; 

case CURRENT_STATE is 
    when RST =>
        o_address <= "0000000000000000";

        if(i_start = '1') then
            NEXT_STATE <= S0;
        else 
            NEXT_STATE <= RST;
        end if;

    --other cases

    when others =>

end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latch is inferred because your "when" has no "else".

If there is a reset (RST) o_address is set to zero. Fine.
But when the reset goes away what then?
It has to stay that way according to your code so a latch is inferred.

So make sure you assign to o_address  in the 'others' section and the latch goes away.

---

As a side note: you would normally not use a reset signal in a combinatorial circuit. Generally speaking you reset a register.

Comment: interesting...when others does not qualify as covering all remaining cases like else does? Seems to me that it would...at least logically but maybe not syntax wise

Comment: I am more used to Verilog but I think 'others' is used with `when` only in a `case`.

Comment: others is fairly broad you can go others -> to assign vectors of unknown size

Comment: that is in a case though

Comment: @DKNguyen Ahh I missed that due to the weird (to me) indenting.

Comment: Also,  if you need storage, not a good idea to assign outputs in a combinatorial process : that's a good way to get latches Better to assign in a clocked process, which would give you a register.

Comment: I assigned o_address in all cases and in others, but now I get the warning "design project has port o_address driven by constant 0" for all bits of o_address (from [15] to [0])

Comment: Well, if you always assign zero's that is a correct warning.

Answer (score 1):

> > o_address <= "00000000000000";

is the only assignment it ever gets. It is never assigned another value anywhere. Once it gets set that way, it stays that way forever, hence constant.

The latch is because when others does nothing so all values needs to be remembered going into the case before leaving.

You can fix this by using if statements under when others to check and reassign the same value taken from its source (not itself) or a constant before leaving so that nothing needs to be latched. Basically, make sure that if a signal is assigned a value in one branch then it is assigned a value in all branches. Do not assign a value to a signal in one branch but not another.